# Access current time step in scipy.integrate.odeint within the function

Tags: python, scipy

Is there a way to access what the current time step is in `scipy.integrate.odeint`?

I am trying to solve a system of ODEs where the form of the ode depends on whether or not a population will be depleted.  Basically I take from population `x` provided `x` doesn't go below a threshold.  If the amount I need to take this timestep is greater than that threshold I will take all of `x` to that point and the rest from `z`.

I am trying to do this by checking how much I will take this time step, and then allocating between populations `x` and `z` in the DEs.

To do this I need to be able to access the step size within the ODE solver to calculate what will be taken this time step. I am using `scipy.integrate.odeint` - is there a way to access the time step within the function defining the odes?

Alternatively, can you access what the last time was in the solver? I know it won't necessarily be the next time step, but it's likely a good enough approximation for me if that is the best I can do. Or is there another option I've not thought of to do this?

The below MWE is not my system of equations but what I could come up with to try to illustrate what I'm doing. The problem is that on the first time step, if the time step were 1 then the population will go too low, but since the timestep will be small, initially you can take all from `x`.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.interactive(False)

tend = 5
tspan = np.linspace(0.0, tend, 1000)

A = 3
B = 4.09
C = 1.96
D = 2.29

def odefunc(P,t):

    x = P[0]
    y = P[1]
    z = P[2]

    if A * x - B * x * y < 0.6:
        dxdt = A/5 * x
        dydt = -C * y + D * x * y
        dzdt = - B * z * y
    else:
        dxdt = A * x - B * x * y
        dydt = -C * y + D * x * y
        dzdt = 0


    dPdt = np.ravel([dxdt, dydt, dzdt])

    return dPdt

init = ([0.75,0.95,100])

sol = odeint(odefunc, init, tspan, hmax = 0.01)
x = sol[:, 0]
y = sol[:, 1]
z = sol[:, 2]

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(tspan,x)
plt.plot(tspan,y)
plt.plot(tspan,z)
```

Comment: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/14765/scipy-integrate-odeint-how-can-odeint-access-a-parameter-set-that-is-evolving-i

Comment: Thanks @Joe I take from this that what I am wanting to do is not possible.  If anyone knows another approach that might work, would love to hear.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can hack something together that might work.
You could log `t` but you have to be aware that the values
*might* not be constantly increasing. This depends on the ODE algorithm and how it works (forward, backward, and central finite differences).

But it will give you an idea where about you are.

```
logger = [] # visible in odefunc

def odefunc(P,t):

    x = P[0]
    y = P[1]
    z = P[2]

    print(t)
    logger.append(t)

    if logger: # if the list is not empty
        if logger[-1] > 2.5: # then read the last value 
            print('hua!')

    if A * x - B * x * y < 0.6:
        dxdt = A/5 * x
        dydt = -C * y + D * x * y
        dzdt = - B * z * y
    else:
        dxdt = A * x - B * x * y
        dydt = -C * y + D * x * y
        dzdt = 0


    dPdt = np.ravel([dxdt, dydt, dzdt])

    return dPdt

print(logger)
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the another answer, time may not be strictly increasing at each call to the ODE function in `odeint`, especially for stiff problems.

The most robust way to handle this kind of discontinuity in the ode function is to use an event to find the location of the zero of `(A * x - B * x * y) - 0.6` in your example.  For a discontinuous solution, use a terminal event to stop the computation precisely at the zero, and then change the ode function.  In `solve_ivp` you can do this with the `events` parameter.  See the [solve ivp documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html) and specifically the examples related to the cannonball trajectories.  `odeint` does not support events, and `solve_ivp` has an LSODA method available that calls the same Fortran library as `odeint`.

Here is a short example, but you may want to additionally check that `sol1` reached the terminal event before solving for `sol2`.

```
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

tend = 10

def discontinuity_zero(t, y):
    return y[0] - 10

discontinuity_zero.terminal = True

def ode_func1(t, y):
    return y

def ode_func2 (t, y):
    return -y**2

sol1 = solve_ivp(ode_func1, t_span=[0, tend], y0=[1], events=discontinuity_zero, rtol=1e-8)
t1 = sol1.t[-1]
y1 = [sol1.y[0, -1]]
print(f'time={t1}  y={y1}   discontinuity_zero={discontinuity_zero(t1, y1)}')

sol2 = solve_ivp(ode_func2, t_span=[t1, tend], y0=y1, rtol=1e-8)

plt.plot(sol1.t, sol1.y[0,:])
plt.plot(sol2.t, sol2.y[0,:])
plt.show()
```

This prints the following, where the time of the discontinuity is accurate to 7 digits.

```
time=2.302584885712467  y=[10.000000000000002]   discontinuity_zero=1.7763568394002505e-15
```