# Accessing current step size in solve_ivp and forwarding it to function to be integrated

Tags: python, scipy

In the function I'm trying to integrate with `solve_ivp` I need the current step size as parameter. Unfortunately it is not enough to just calculate the potential step size beforehand due to the adaptive internal step size. Therefore I was wondering if there is a way of retrieving the currently used step size and forwarding it to the function to be integrated?
There was a similar question earlier ([Access time step in scipy solve_ivp()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54835006/2546099)), but there this value was used in the gradient, and by a second look could be omitted. Unfortunately, I do not have that option. Alternatively, an internal counter is suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58908314/2546099
Or do I have to write my own integrator for that?

In my function to be integrated I first propagate the input data a time step in the future (i.e. the time step `solve_ivp()` currently is using), calculate the response to that future data, and transform the data back to the original time afterwards. Thus, to get the response to the data in the future, I need the time step applied to my function.

Comment: *"I need the current step size as parameter."*  My initial reaction to that is *You're doing it wrong* ™.  That breaks the underlying model of how `solve_ivp` and other adaptive solvers for ODEs work.  Could you explain *why* you need the current step size?  What are your differential equations?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: I added a short explanation to that, I hope it is sufficient.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand your explanation.  The underlying mathematical model solved by `solve_ivp` is a system of differential equations with continuous time, i.e. `dx/dt = F(t, x)` for a vector `x`.  There is no time step in that model.  Can you describe the mathemtical model that you are trying to solve?  What do you mean when you say you "propagate the input data a time step in the future"?

Comment: I suspect you have an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  You are asking how to solve Y, but the real problem is X.  That's why I would like to know more about the equations that you are trying to solve.

Comment: I'm following a similar process as is it suggested for example for solving the UPPE (unidirectional pulse propagation equation) in https://doi.org/10.1140/epjst/e2011-01503-3. Here the process within the equation to solve is to move the input field by dt into the future, calculate the effects acting on the field, and move the field back to t0 afterwards. Thus my interest in getting dt from solve_ivp().

Comment: I am also searching a way to access `dt`in order to solve a "Dirac Detla" in the ODE.

Answer (score 1):

Old thread but I wanted to do something very similar. In my case, I wanted to model the temperature of a plate with PID-controlled heating and cooling. The proportional and integral terms can be evaluated with solve_ivp as-is, but the derivative term requires a timestep. My workaround was to modify the `__init__` method of the OdeSolver class used by solve_ivp prior to calling it:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
from scipy.integrate._ivp.base import OdeSolver


og_init = OdeSolver.__init__


def newinit(self, fun, t0, y0, t_bound, vectorized, support_complex=False):
    fun2 = lambda t, y: fun(self, t, y)
    og_init(self, fun2, t0, y0, t_bound, vectorized, support_complex=support_complex)


OdeSolver.__init__ = newinit
```

Now instead of passing in a function with arguments `(t, y)`, I pass in a function with arguments `(obj, t, y)`. The lambda function above will pass `self` in for `obj`, giving your function access to the attributes of the `OdeSolver` instance, which includes the solver's previous accepted timestep `t_old`.

Now the function I'm integrating will look like this:

```
def myfunc(solverobj, t, y):
    if solverobj.t_old:  # Initially, t_old is None
        dt = t - solverobj.t_old
    else:
        dt = 1e-6  # It's up to you how to handle this part
    dy = the_function_youre_integrating(t, y, dt)
    return dy
```

Note that you'll need to decide how your function should behave at the start, since `solverobj.t_old` will be `None` during initial timestep determination.

Then you call `solve_ivp` as usual:

```
s = solve_ivp(myfunc, [t_0, t_end], y_init, method='BDF')
```

Hopefully this is helpful to someone!